# Setting an env variable accessible to the gocd pipeline

Tags: go-cd

I have a need to be able to update a environment variable from the linux gocd agents . This environment variable should be accessible from within any pipeline that runs on the agent. Documentation i have read so far talks about using the environment variables created in the gocd environment. However this is not my requirement.

I have tried the following steps so far:

```
 - Logged into the agent as go user and set an environment variable ( export VARA=XXX)
 - Tried to echo this variable from a pipeline in gocd that prints this variable, in vain.
 - Also tried specifying the variable in bash_profile, bashrc and executed the source command in the same gocd task that echoes the variable
```

For some reason, gocd pipeline doesnt seem to see this variable. Please let me know if you have any pointers.

Answer (score 2):

If you put the variable in the `~/.bash_profile` or `~.bashrc` files, you can wrap your actual commands in a `bash -l -c 'your command here`. The `-l` forces bash to behave as a login shell, and read those files.